# Entity Framework Core attempting to update column marked as Identity in model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0, identity-column

I have a database table where one of the columns is an `IDENTITY` column (not the primary key which is set manually). My EF Core model looks like this:

```
public class Model
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...Other fields...

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AnotherId { get; set; }
}
```

Despite the annotation, when I do an update on the table I find that the SQL which is generated tries to update the `IDENTITY` column:

```
UPDATE [Model] SET ... [AnotherId] = @p10 ...
WHERE [Id] = @p29;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

This obviously fails, causing the an exception to be thrown. I am using Entity Core 2.0 and upgrading to 2.1 is currently not an option. Any ideas why the data annotation is being ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute you likely want to use is:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#data-annotations).

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm still not clear in the documentation where it shows that the expereinced behavior should be happening for `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` but this solved my issue for now.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx) in [`OnModelCreating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx) of the `Context` class. Something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
    .Entity<Model>()
    .Property(c => c.AnotherId )
    .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
}
```

Also in EF Core 2 it should be something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Property(c => c.AnotherId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
modelBuilder.Property(p => p.AnotherId )
            .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good answer but I have been using attributes over the fluent API where possible so I'm going to go with the solution suggested by @mjwills in the comments.

Comment: @SBFrancies *Fluent API is another way to configure your domain classes. Fluent API provides more functionality for configuration than DataAnnotations.* https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_fluent_api.htm

Comment: Thanks, I know that and am using the Fluent API to fill in the gaps where it is not possible to use data annotations. I just prefer to use the data annotations where possible and have found for the most part they have met my needs.

Comment: As a note, these extension methods should be in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer assembly.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me in EF Core 3.1 was this:

```
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<YourTableName>().Property(c => c.YourPropertyName).UseIdentityColumn().ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
    }
```

Without ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate() I was seeing the same error as the OP when updating existing records. It looks therefore as though UseIdentityColumn() is equivalent to calling ValueGeneratedOnAdd().